# Riemann integrability of $f(x) = 0$ if $x=0$ or $x = 1/n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $f(x)=1$ otherwise

Tags: riemann-integration

> Let 
>   $$
> f(x) = \begin{cases}
>   0 & \text{if $x=0$ or $x = 1/n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$,} \\
>   1 & \text{otherwise.}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   Is this function Riemann-Stieltjes integrable in $[0,1]$?

For the upper Riemann-Stieltjes integral, all $f(x)$ would be $1$ for any partition so it's $1$.

For the lower Riemann-Stieltjes integral, for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ of which $f(1/n)=0$, is there a chance of this integral becoming different from upper integral?

Comment: To say that a function is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable, you need another function, which you have not specified.

Comment: what iif $\alpha(x) =x?$

Comment: Then it is just the usual Riemann integral.

Comment: @edm pleas check my answer below if you have chance

Comment: @JackerySmith: I took the liberty of formatting your function using TeX's 'cases` environment. ;)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang that liberty always welcome. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your function is discontinuous in only countable number of points, hence it's Riemann integrable. Intuitively you can make the partition such that it's very small around the discontinuity points.

Refer to the link below

[Proof that a function with a countable set of discontinuities is Riemann integrable without the notion of measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263189/proof-that-a-function-with-a-countable-set-of-discontinuities-is-riemann-integra)

Comment: how could I refine my mathjax representation? any advice?

Comment: is above function Riemann integral irrespective of my choice of $\alpha$(increasing function for Riemann integration)?

Comment: from the above link, I can't understand what " require the notion of sets of measure 0" means.