# Why the integrals and derivatives do not kill each other in case of Thomae function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

The following is the Thomae function:

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{q} & if \quad x = \frac{p}{q}, p \in \mathbb{Z}, q \in \mathbb{N},\text{ gcd(p, q) = 1 }    \\
      0 &  if \quad  x\in \mathbb{Q}^c \quad or \quad  x=0. 
   \end{cases} $$

My professor said that integrals and derivatives do not kill each other for Thomae function because $\int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt = 0$ and $\frac {d}{dx} \int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt = 0.$

**My question is:**

I tried to calculate $\int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt$ and I got $\frac{x}{q}$ and not $0.$ Could anyone show me the detailed calculation of this please?

Comment: Isn’t the function $0$ almost everywhere so the Lebesgue integral would be $0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each partition $P$ of $[0,x]$, the lower sum of $f$ with respect to $P$ is $0$. Therefore, if $f$ is integrable, $\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt=0$.

And $f$ is integrable since it is bounded and the set of points at which it is discontinuous is countable.

Comment: What theorem are you using ?

Comment: A bounded real function whose domain is an interval $[a,b]$ of $\Bbb R$ is Riemann-integrable if and only if the set$$\{x\in[a,b]\mid f\text{ is discontinuous at }x\}$$has measure $0$. But I can prove that $f$ is integrable without it too.

Comment: But I took this information before studying Lebesgue measure ..... so do you have a theorem without using the measure notion?

Comment: You will find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263189/proof-that-a-function-with-a-countable-set-of-discontinuities-is-riemann-integra) a proof (without Lebesgue measure) of the fact that a bounded real function whose domain is an interval $[a,b]$ of $\Bbb R$ is Riemann-integrable if it has only a countable set of points at which it is discontinuous. Or you can use the fact that, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there are only finitely many numbers $y$ on $[0,x]$ such that $f(y)>\varepsilon$ to prove that $\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt=0$.