# Prove this function is integrable over an interval

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, riemann-integration

Let $f:[0,2] \to R$ defined as $f(x)= \begin{cases} 1 & x \neq 1 \\ 0 & x = 1 \end{cases}$

Prove that $f$ is integrable in $[0,2]$ and obtain its integral.

Well since the function it's not continuous nor monotonic, then I think this must be proved by definition, but I don't know how to find the partitions, upper and lower sum, etc.

Comment: Every function with a finite number of discontinuities is Riemann integrable. Idea: Split your interval such that the discontinuities are on the boundary of the partition intervals.

Comment: One can even prove this holds, if the set of discontinuities is countable (cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263189/proof-that-a-function-with-a-countable-set-of-discontinuities-is-riemann-integra).

Comment: I edited your question to make your function definition for $f(x)$ more readable using begin{cases}...end{cases}. This might be useful to you in the future.

Comment: Note that $f$ is piecewise continuous in [0,2] and hence integrable. To obtain the integral, simply break the integral at the point $1$ and calculate.

Comment: Thanks a lot aras and @Benjamin, so I can split the interval into the partitions $P_1=[0,1]$ and $P_2=[1,2]$ since $x=1$ is a point of discontinuity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

Let $ \epsilon>0 $ small enough.

Consider the partage
$$P=(0,1-\frac{\epsilon}{3},1+\frac{\epsilon}{3},2)$$

then

$$U(f,P)-L(f,P)=$$
$$(1-1)(\frac{1-\epsilon}{3}-0)+$$
$$(1-0)(1+\frac{\epsilon}{3}-(1-\frac{\epsilon}{3}))+(1-1)(2-(1+\frac{\epsilon}{3}))=$$
$$\frac{2\epsilon}{3}<\epsilon$$

Its integral is given by

$$\int_0^1f+\int_1^2f=$$
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(\int_0^{1-\frac 1n}dx+\int_{1+\frac 1n}^2dx)=$$
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(1-\frac 1n)+(2-1-\frac 1n)=$$
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(2-\frac 2n)=2$$m

Comment: Thanks! So I took the suggested partition $P$, then I must find the upper sum and the lower sum? That is finding the suprema and infima?

Comment: @MarioM21 I applied Cauchy criterion for integrability with Darboux's sums.

Comment: Ok, I think I can't use that criterion because we haven't proved it in my calculus course, what can I do to prove it by definition?

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, can you please edit your answer and write the complete proof? It would help me a lot!

Comment: @MarioM21 what are the lines you need to clarify.

Comment: After considering such partition, how do you proceed from there to get to the fact that the upper and lower sums are smaller than epsilon?

Comment: @MarioM21 Hi, please have a look now.